# Subtract column value from date in days or months

Tags: postgresql, datetime, postgresql-11

I want to subtract the value in column `lag_days` from `current_date`.
Usually I would do `current_date - interval '1 day'`

I'm getting syntax error on the following example to subtract by days:

```
dkarchive=> select current_date - interval lag_days day from example_tbl;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "day"
LINE 1: select current_date - interval lag_days day from example_tb...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the interval syntax to begin with. You can simply subtract an integer from a `date` value, e.g. `current_date - 1` is "yesterday".

```
select current_date - lag_days
from the_table;
```

If you do want to use an interval, the `make_interval()` function is quite useful for this:

```
select current_date - make_interval(days => lag_days)
from the_table;
```

There is however a difference between the two queries: the first one returns a `date` value, the second one a `timestamp` value.

Comment: You can also do `select current_date - interval '1 day' * lag_days`.